# Etymologies of injections and surjecteions

Tags: functions, terminology

Why one-to-one functions are called "injections" and onto functions are called "surjections"?

Answer (score 3):

French prepositions: in and sur (meaning on).

Comment: It was introduced by Bourbaki, apparently. See the entry for “Injection” here: http://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html